# Turning off public access to AWS S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I understand that you can grant read/write to internal AWS account resources like lambda when you turn off public access. However what if I need to be able to read an S3 object from an external host, via the S3 URL? Sure I know I could add a public API endpoint to serve up the S3 asset. However if I use something like `<img src=""/>` that doesn't help me. If I try to perform a GET on the S3 url at this point, I get a 403. I'm wondering in this case that I have to leave 'public access' on?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to access objects in private Amazon S3 buckets.

#### Use S3 API calls

You can use API calls using the AWS CLI or an AWS SDK. These API calls require AWS credentials that have `GetObject` permission to access the bucket. They do not require the bucket to be public.

#### Use a pre-signed URL

Alternatively, you can generate an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which provides time-limited access to private objects in Amazon S3. The URL can be used in `<img src=...>` tags.

The pre-signed URL can be generated in a few lines of code without the need to call AWS. It is basically a hashed signature that uses some AWS credentials to authorise access to the private object. This option appears most suitable for your use-case.